# lua tables, simplest way to overload __tostring

Tags: lua, tostring, metatable

Thanks to all the Lua stackoverflow folks who have discussed how to customized printing tables. After much reading, I post the following   and   ask the Lua gurus....

- is this the simplest way?
- is it too simple (i.e. broken in some way I don't understand)?

Note that the following:

- allows for private fields (just start their name with "_") that are not to be printed
- does not add size to the `metatable` of every object.

My approach rewrites the default `tostring` method.

```
_tostring =  _tostring or tostring
function tostring(t)
  if type(t) == "table" then 
    status, stuff = pcall(function() return t:s() end) 
    if status then 
      return stuff 
  end end 
  return _tostring(t) 
end
```

The above is a little evil (that call to pcall... not my proudest bit of code but, heh, it works).

In any case, now `tostring` makes the method call `t:s()` to an object which we can define using the following homebrew object system:

```
Object={}

function Object:new(o)
   o = o or {} 
   setmetatable(o,self)  
   self.__index = self
   return o
end
```

Here's the default definition of `:s()` -- which can  be customized in sub-classes.

```
function Object:s()
  -- can be customized in subclasses
  local out,sep="{",":"
  for x,y in pairs(self) do 
    if string.sub(x,1,1) ~= "_" then
      out = out..sep..x.." "..y 
      sep = " :"
  end end  
  return out .. '}'
end
```

e.g.

```
x=Object:new{a=1, _b=2};print(x)
{:a 1}
```

Comment: Why overwrite tostring rather than setting up a __tostring metamethod?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows a working ode, and the OP is asking for [codereview.se].

Comment: @hjpotter92 _working code_ is not a valid off-topic reason on Stack Overflow. He's asking for an _improvement to a specific problem/issue_. Which is off-topic on Code Review anyway

Answer (score 13):

> is this the simplest way?

By far, no. The simplest way would be to add a `__tostring` function to your metatable.

```
function MyClass:__tostring()
    return "<MyClass: "..self.foo..">"
end
```

> does not add size to the metatable of every object.

This is not a concern. Only one metatable should exist per class. The memory usage of one entry in a table is negligible.

Overwriting `tostring` is both ugly and potentially dangerous: what if you (or someone else) is using a library whose objects have an `s` method that has side effects?

Comment: Note that `__tostring` in Lua 5.1 will not affect calls to `lua_tolstring`. This was fixed in 5.2 and later